# Android Make hyperlinks in textview clickable

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, linkify

I am getting some HTML from server and showing in Textview. The HTML have some hyperlinks. I want that when user clicks some hyperlink, it opens that link's url in device browser but it is not working. I have read about Linkify and using following:

```
TextView articleDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.articledescription);
articleDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(articleInfo.getArticle_body()));
Linkify.addLinks(articleDescription, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

but its too not working. Any idea...???

Sorry guys, actually I have recently noticed that the hyperlinks are relative to the server so I think that is the reason the intent for browser is not being fired. I have sample HTML text:

```
<p><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">Since I began reporting for It&rsquo;s Relevant in June, I have come across some amazing people living and working in Stamford. Over the past 6 months, I have had the opportunity to share their stories and report on issues affecting the city. Here are some of my favorite pieces from     2011:</span></span></p> <p><br /><a href="/content/7298/Bakers_Keep_Up_With_The_Kardashians_?ref=qmf10j"><span style="color: #000080;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">Bakers Keep up with the Kardashians</span></span></span></a></p> <p><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">This story combines two of my favorite things, the Kardashian sister&rsquo;s and cake! Deb and Dina are so talented and it was great to see them at work. </span></span></p> <p><br /><a href="www.itsrelevant.com/content/7508/Yankees_GM_Set_To_Jump_Off_Building?ref=qmf10j"><span style="color: #000080;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">Yankees GM Set to Jump Off Building</span></span></span></a></p> <p><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">Never in my life did I think I would interview the General Manager of the Yankees, let alone on the rooftop of a 22-story building!</span></span></p> <p><a href="/content/6782/Fashion_Show_Features_Cancer_Survivors?ref=0yk17d"><br /><span style="color: #000080;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">Breast Cancer Fashion Show</span></span></span><span style="color: #000000;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;"> </span></span></span></a></p> <p><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">These women are truly amazing! So many people are affected by cancer and the Paint the Town Pink committee spent October bringing awareness to the disease. </span></span></p> <p><br /><a href="/content/5275/Downed_Trees_Remain_Problem?ref=qmf10j"><span style="color: #0000ff;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;">Downed Trees Remain Problem </span></span></span></a></p>
```

Now any suggestion what to do which such kind of data? OR some kind of regular expression so that I can replace relative paths to the servers absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this.It may Helpfull..

```
  TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    webview =new WebView(this);
    webview.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>"));
    tv.setClickable(true);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    URLSpan[] urlSpans = tv.getUrls();
    for ( URLSpan urlSpan : urlSpans )  
    {  
        webview.loadUrl( urlSpan.getURL() ); 
    }
```

and look this link. http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this:

```
TextView articleDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.articledescription);
articleDescription.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
articleDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(articleInfo.getArticle_body()));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.*example*);
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```