# Open list of relative urls absolutely in android TextView?

Tags: android, html, textview

In my application (target 4.0), I have a chunk of HTML (which was pulled and parsed from a webpage) that I am displaying in a TextView. This HTML contains a large number of links (up to 100), most of which are relative, but some are absolute. I want the user to be able to click these relative urls URLs to launch a web browser.

How can I do this *without* going through the HTML and changing the URLs? Can I tap into a link click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your `WebView` and override [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) (and perhaps [`onLoadResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) too).

Comment: This is inside a TextView, but if I can't find a way to do it there maybe I'll just use a WebView. Thanks!

Comment: I saw this and thought it wouldn't work, but reading over it again it seems I may be able to capture all the link clicks, and then launch an activity which decides how to launch into a web browser. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: It made the most sense to just use a WebView and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading, launching an ACTION_VIEW intent on click. I did this in conjunction with WebView's loadDataWithBaseURL, setting the BaseUrl to the url needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can match URL (and other patterns) using `Linkify`and you can parse your content to use `<a>` tags like this:

[Android Make hyperlinks in textview clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409033/android-make-hyperlinks-in-textview-clickable)

In other words, you need the `href` to contain a fully qualified URL, but you can still display the relative URL to the user.

No client URL works without full qualification, so you need to give the client a context. But this allows you to display relative URL's to the user.